Prove that $\frac{1}{4-ab}+\frac{1}{4-bc}+\frac{1}{4-ac} \leq 1$ where a,b,c are all real positive where $a^4 + b^4 + c^4 = 3$
The Question is given above, and the main thing is that any kind of am-gm is not working. The gap between $a^4 + b^4 + c^4$ and 4-ab type terms is very unnatural making it harder for me to relate them in inequalities.
My Approaches and Thoughts:
To prove: $\frac{1}{4-ab}+\frac{1}{4-bc}+\frac{1}{4-ac} \leq 1$
Wlog let $a \geq b \geq c$
Thus $ab \geq ac \geq bc$
Therfore by using simple boundations
$\frac{1}{4-ab}+\frac{1}{4-bc}+\frac{1}{4-ac} \leq \frac{1}{4-bc}+\frac{1}{4-bc}+\frac{1}{4-bc} = \frac{3}{4-bc} \leq \frac{3}{4-c^2}$
Since c is the minimum of all three $a,b,c$ Thus the max of c will be when $a=b=c=1$ in which this $\frac{3}{4-c^2} = \frac{3}{3} = 1$ Thus $\frac{3}{4-c^2} \geq 1$ But I had to prove the other way and it didnt helped me.
Can someone help me prove this.

Whoever has degraded my question, please let me know the problem in this so that I can improve it in future

I didn't downvote, but you should include your tryings, and not just say that am-gm didn't work.

I have fixed that problem @DietrichBurde

The first inequality after "boundations" is wrong: $$x\geq bc\implies 4-x \leq 4-bc \implies \frac{1}{4-x} \geq \frac{1}{4-bc}.$$

@Gonçalo Yes then $\frac{3}{4-ab} \leq \frac{3}{4-a^2}$ which willl have min value 1 and thus will be $\geq 1$

Firstly we can multiply both sides by 3 to get
$$ \frac{3}{4-bc}+\frac{3}{4-ca}+\frac{3}{4-ab}=3-\frac{1-ab}{4-ab}-\frac{1-bc}{4-bc}-\frac{1-ca}{4-ca}\leq 3 $$
which is equivalent to
$$ \frac{ab}{4-ab}+\frac{bc}{4-bc}+\frac{ca}{4-ca}\leq \frac{1}{4-ab}+\frac{1}{4-bc}+\frac{1}{4-ca} $$
and now we can muliply by $(4-ab)(4-bc)(4-ca)$ and simplify to get
$$ 24(ab+bc+ca)+3a^2b^2c^2\leq 48+9(a^2bc+ab^2c+abc^2). $$
To prove this we will prove two equalities which added together will finish the proof
$$ (1) \quad \quad \quad  3a^2b^2c^2\leq a^2bc+ab^2c+abc^2 $$
$$ (2) \quad \quad \quad 24(ab+bc+ca)\leq  48+8(a^2bc+ab^2c+abc^2).$$
To prove $(1)$ we can divide both sides by $abc$ (we assume it's nonzero because in other case the inequality is obvious) to get
$$ 3abc \leq a+b+c$$
but using our condition (AM-GM) $\sqrt[3]{a^4b^4c^4}\leq \sqrt[4]{\frac 3 3}=1$ so $abc\leq 1$ and then we get
$$ abc\leq \sqrt[3]{abc}\leq \frac{a+b+c}{3} $$
which prooves $(1).$ To prove $(2)$ we can divide both sides by 8 and then square them to get
$$ 9(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)+18abc(a+b+c)\leq 36+12abc(a+b+c)+a^2b^2c^2(a+b+c)^2$$
which simplifies to
$$ (*)\quad \quad \quad 9(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2) \leq 27+(3-abc(a+b+c))^2. $$
The square is obviously nonnegative and also $a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2\leq a^4+b^4+c^4=3$ so $(*)$ is true and so is $(2).$ That finishes proof of our inequality

$$\dfrac{1}{4-ab}\leq\dfrac{1}{4-\sqrt{\frac{a^4+b^4}{2}}}=\dfrac{1}{4-\sqrt{\frac{3-c^4}{2}}}.$$
Consider $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{4-\sqrt{\frac{3-x}{2}}}$ on $I=[0,3].$ You can take the ugly derivatives and prove this function is concave on $I$ and finish the problem via Jensen's:
$$\sum_{a,b,c} f(a^4)\leq 3f(1) = 1.$$
It might be easier to consider:
$$f(x) = (h\circ g)(x) = h(g(x))$$
where $g(x) = \sqrt{\dfrac{3-x}{2}}$, which is decreasing and concave, and $h(x) = \dfrac{1}{4-x}$, which is increasing and convex, and then prove a general theorem about this composition about being concave without computing second derivative.

Alternatively, we can use the TL (tangent line) method.
We have
$$\frac{1}{4 - \sqrt[4]{x}} \le \frac13 + \frac{1}{36}(x - 1), \quad x \in [0, 3]. \tag{1}$$
(Note: The RHS is $f(1) + f'(1)(x - 1)$. Using
$\frac{1}{4 - \sqrt[4]{x}}
\le \frac{1}{4 - (1+\sqrt{x})/2}$ (AM-GM), it suffices to prove that $\frac{1}{4 - (1+\sqrt{x})/2}\le \frac13 + \frac{1}{36}(x - 1)$ which is easy.)
Note that $a^4b^4 + b^4c^4 + c^4a^4 \le (a^4 + b^4 + c^4)^2/3 = 3$. In (1), letting $x = a^4b^4, b^4c^4, c^4a^4$, respectively, add them up to get
$$\frac{1}{4-ab}+\frac{1}{4-bc}+\frac{1}{4-ac} \le 1 + \frac{1}{36}(a^4b^4 + b^4c^4 + c^4 a^4 - 3) \le 1.$$
We are done.
